# search in arrray javascript

Tags: javascript, html, binary-search-tree

I want to look for items in an array My problem is that it returns -1 when the size of the array is 4 or 6

Here are my tests:

```
var tab = [1,2,3] ;
binarySearch(tab,3);
2
var tab = [1,2,3,4,5];

binarySearch(tab,3);
2
binarySearch(tab,2);
-1
```

```
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of example implementations of binary search across the internet.

Comment: Why not use `indexOf`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 binary search is incredibly faster than indexOf depending on the size of the array. For any significantly large sorted array, binary search is exponentially faster.

Comment: @TKoL: Not when you're using a manual implementation of binary search in JS, compared to a native, optimized method.

Comment: or the `.find(findFunc)` or `.findIndex(findFunc)` array methods, if `indexOf` doesn't cut it?

@TKoL Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: @Cerbrus gurvinder did not ask about a native optimized method of binary search. He asked about indexOf. I guarantee you binarySearch, manually implemented in JS, for lists with millions / billions of integers, will be faster than indexOf

Comment: @nadavvadan given that you don't know the context for why he's using this function, how could you know how 'premature' it is? Maybe he's working on an incredibly mature application that requires binary search because searching through other methods is taking too long. You're making some weird assumptions.

Comment: Hi there is no use answering this question. This is from a student of mine who asked this during a graded lab session. By the way, the full code is here: https://www.lri.fr/~kn/teaching/js/interro/files/binary_search.js and the answer is, the function is buggy because it leaves imid as a floating point number (which could end up being 3.5) which is not a valid array index. You have to round it using Math.trunc. Also I know who you are and will fail you for this course.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code i wrote for my open source [forensic js](http://github.com/harrison1822/forensic) library. this is how i did binary search for my array contains utility method to help in searching for all kind of data inside an array. hope you find it useful. i simply copied the portion and modified it a bit.

```
/**
        *@description - default callback sorting function
        *@param {*} value1 - comparison arg 1
        *@param {*} value2 - comparison arg 2
        *@returns {Number}
        */
        var FN_SORT = function (value1, value2) {
            var type1 = typeof value1,
            type2 = typeof value2;
            if (type1 === 'number' && type2 === 'number') {
                return value1 - value2;
            }
            else if (type1 === 'number') {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (type2 === 'number') {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (value1 < value2) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (value1 > value2) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        },

        /**
        *@description - default callback searching function
        *@param {*} value1 - comparison arg 1
        *@param {*} value2 - comparison arg 2
        *@param {Boolean} [casesensitive=false] - boolean value indicating if the comparison is case sensitive or not
        *@returns {Number}
        */
        FN_SERACH = function (value1, value2, casesensitive) {
            if (!casesensitive) {
                value1 = typeof value1 === 'string' ? value1.toLowerCase() : value1;
                value2 = typeof value2 === 'string' ? value2.toLowerCase() : value2;
            }

            var type1 = typeof value1,
            type2 = typeof value2;
            if (type1 === 'number' && type2 === 'number') {
                return value1 - value2;
            }
            else if (type1 === 'number') {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (type2 === 'number') {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (value1 < value2) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (value1 > value2) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        },
        /**
        *@memberof Forensic#util
        *@description - searches an Array for a key. returns key index position if found or -1 if not found
        *@param {Array} array - array to search from
        *@param {mixed} key - key to search
        *@param {Boolean} [casesensitive=false] - a boolean value indicating if key or item search should respect case
        *@param {Function} [fnsort] - sorting function which is optional. your sorting function must return a number, while it accepts two
        *arguments, the first value, second value.
        *the sorting function should return -1 if argument one should come before argument two, 1 if argument two should come before argument
        *one, zero if the order is unimportant
        *@param {Function} [fnsearch] - searching function which is optional. your searching function must return a number, while it accepts three
        *arguments, the first value is the value being searched for, second value, a third casesensitive value as you specified in argument two.
        *the searching function should return -1 if argument one should come before argument two, 1 if argument two should come before argument
        *one, zero if the two are equal. it may seem redundant having to specify sorting and searching function at the same time. it is done for
        *performance reasons, sorting functions will not require case conversion while searching functions may require case conversion
        *@returns {Number}
        *@Exception {Exception} argument one is not an Array
        */
            arrayContains = function (array, key, casesensitive, fnsort, fnsearch) {
                if (typeof key === 'undefined' || array.length === 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
                fnsort = fnsort ? fnsort : FN_SORT;
                fnsearch = fnsearch ? fnsearch : FN_SERACH;

                var low = 0,
                high = array.length - 1,
                middle = parseInt((high + low + 1) / 2, 10),
                locationindex = -1,
                searchindex = 0;
                array.sort(fnsort);
                do {
                    searchindex = fnsearch(key, array[middle], casesensitive);
                    if (searchindex === 0) {
                        locationindex = middle;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (searchindex < 0) {
                            high = middle - 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            low = middle + 1;
                        }
                        middle = parseInt((high + low + 1) / 2, 10);
                    }
                }
                while (low <= high && locationindex === -1);
                return locationindex;
            };
        var array = [0, 0, 0, 3];
        alert(arrayContains(array, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

var found = array1.find(function(element) {
  return element > 10;
});

console.log(found);
// expected output: 12
```

**this how you can search in array see** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const tab = [1,2,3,4]

console.log(binarySearch(tab,4))//3


function binarySearch(arr,item){

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if(arr[i]===item){

      return i

    }
  }
}
```